# Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'myApp.view1' is not available

Tags: angularjs

Please help me to organize code correctly. I'm trying to change structure of simple angular-seed project in order to learn how to act with it. As I see I have troubles with structuring modules & sub-modules

File app.js

```
    angular.module('myApp.view1');
    angular.module('myApp.view2');
angular.module('myApp', [
  'myApp.view1',
  'myApp.view2',
  'ngRoute'
]);
var myApp = angular.module('myApp');
myApp.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when('/view1', {
      templateUrl: 'views/view1.html',
      controller: 'View1Ctrl'
    })

  .when('/view2', {
    templateUrl: 'views/view2.html',
    controller: 'View2Ctrl'
  })

  .otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/view1'
  });
}]);
```

Here's view1.js

```
    'use strict';

var view1 = angular.module('myApp.view1');
  view1.controller('View1Ctrl', [function($scope) {
    $scope.firstName = "John";
  }]);
```

And view2.js

```
'use strict';

var view2 = angular.module('myApp.view2');
view2.controller('View2Ctrl', [function($scope) {
$scope.lastName = "Doe";
}]);
```

Comment: I am presuming that this code is from the 'angular-seed' project.  Have you taken a look at Angular modular seed - https://github.com/johannesjo/angular-modular-seed.  That might be the structure you want (depends on how big is your app).  Why do you need sub-modules? Why not just not a flat modular structure with good namespaces, keep things simple?  Most importantly, when you are structuring your app, remember - https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide#application-structure-lift-principle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is because you are accessing the module and not defining them Define them like -

```
angular.module('myApp.view1', []);
angular.module('myApp.view2', []);
```

assuming that the modules have no dependencies.

And do check out my comment on app structure.